# What are some useful resources for learning tuple calculus?

Tags: sql, database-design, relational-database

I've been trying to go over my tuple calculus over and over again. What's worse is that my professor and tutors are not much help during their hours.

Does anyone know a good place to learn about tuple calculus? I'm having a hard time understanding how to "speak" the language in terms of what I want to get from a database.

Comment: Why don't you get another book on the subject?

Comment: well... Google has always been a good resource. For example I just hacked my Diff Eq quiz, while never having worked on the sections, by using google and searching for examples. Its quite a novelty isn't it? *sarcasm*

Comment: With all respect to the internet knowledge that is out there, books provide structured, accurate and consistent source of information specially in academic subjects. This is not to say don't use the internet of course.

Comment: Having queried datbasea at an advanced level for over 30 years, I have never once felt the need to do tuple calculus. SQL is important, the other is just something you need to know enough about to pass the test.

Comment: @EmmadKareem - It sounds like the OP is asking for a recommendation for ANY resource that may help him.  That said I am not sure if this is really ontopic because it is a list question.

Comment: @HLGEM - Do you know how to do tuple calculus?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some good resources on the web where you can learn about Tuple Calculus:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple_relational_calculus

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EUzsy3W4I0g

Answer (score 0):

May I recommend [Tutorial D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D_%28data_language_specification%29)?  [Rel](http://dbappbuilder.sourceforge.net/Rel.php), an implementation thereof is an abstract set of operations for your tuples or record-level structures.

I know you want a LOT of detail on this, but I'm glad to hear questions, I am writing a school-aged text on relational algebra, hopefully to get some folks interested earlier...